# How can I change the layout of page 2 in a pagination of Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, pagination

I have done pagination of my category page. When I click the page2 the design shows like my first category page.

But I want to change the layout of my page2.

How can it be possible?

Comment: in the pagination code you will find paged variable which is a request having page number so use if else or  switch cases to design your page according to page number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if you want different layout for all the other pages except the first, follow this:

As per TwentyTwelve pagination:

```
<?php if( $paged != 0 ) { ?>
   <!-- new layout -->
<?php } else { ?>
   <!-- existing layout -->
<?php } ?>
```

Please note:
`$paged = 0` means the very first page (where `$paged` is not isset), but
`$paged = 2` means the second page

Answer (score 0):

```
    if(isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] == 2){
// do whatever

}
```